# Magento 2: Magento Test Framework(MTF) Detail Document for custom module functional test

Tags: magento2

How to create the functional test for custom module in magento 2. 
Magento team not given proper doc and not mentioned steps to create functional test for custom module.

Any body know in this world ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 official documentation provides a practical example on how to create a functional tests, you can find the details here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/create_test/create_new_test.html